# Doubts about the process of vector operation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation, rotations

Now I´m proving the Rodrigues' rotation formula, and have a question in the process of covering to the  matrix form of formula.
The below is the Rodrigues' rotation formula
$$Rv ⃗= \cos⁡(θ) v ⃗+(1-\cos⁡(θ) )(u ̂u ⃗^T)\cdot v ⃗+sin⁡(θ) [u ̂]_××v ⃗$$
Where $R$ is a rotation matrix and $v ⃗ = [v1,v2,v3]$，$u ̂ =[u1,u2,u3]$ is a unit column vector and $$[u ̂]_×=
\left \{
\begin{matrix}
0&-u3&u2\\
u3&0&-u1\\
-u2&u1&0\\
\end{matrix}
\right\}　
$$   is a  skew-symmetric matrix  of $u ⃗ $.

And this formula converts to matrix form include below :
$$R=\cos⁡(θ) I_{3×3} +(1-\cos⁡(θ))
\left \{
\begin{matrix}
u1 \\
u2 \\
u3\\
\end{matrix}
\right \}
\left \{
\begin{matrix}
u1&u2&u3\\
\end{matrix}
\right \}
+\sin⁡(θ)
\left \{
\begin{matrix}
0&-u3&u2\\
u3&0&-u1\\
-u2&u1&0\\
\end{matrix}
\right\},
$$

Where $I_{3×3}$ is the $3$ by $3$ identity matrix
So my problem is how to do in this process of convert about $v ⃗$ is dropped in the both sides of the equation, and appear the identity matrix $I_{3×3}$ beside the $cos(θ)$.
As far as I know vector division is not defined so I don't know how to convert .

Comment: I edited your post to make it easier to read, if you think I made a mistake feel free to change it. Also see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should be

$$R\vec v= \cos⁡(θ) \vec v +(1-\ cos⁡(θ) )({\hat u}\hat u^T) \vec v +\sin⁡(θ) \hat u \times \vec v$$
Convince yourself that the right-hand side is a sum of 3 elements of $\mathbb R^3$. Note that
$$\cos⁡(θ) \vec v = \cos(\theta ) I_{3\times 3} \vec v, $$
and also you should check if you didn't already know that $$\hat u \times \vec v = [\hat u]_\times \vec v$$ where the right-hand side is matrix multiplication with a vector, and the left-hand side is vector cross product. Substitute the above equalities in, and use distributivity of matrix multiplication $AD+BD+CD = (A+B+C)D$

\begin{align}
R\vec v
&= \cos⁡(θ)I_{3\times 3} \vec v +(1-\ cos⁡(θ) )({\hat u}\hat u^T) \vec v +\sin⁡(θ) [u ̂]_\times \vec v \\
&= \Big[ \cos⁡(θ)I_{3\times 3}  +(1-\ cos⁡(θ) )({\hat u}\hat u^T)  +\sin⁡(θ) [u ̂]_\times \Big] \vec v 
\end{align}
Two matrices $A,B$ of the same shape are equal iff for every vector $\vec v$, $A\vec v = B\vec v$. This allows us to 'cancel' $\vec v$.

Comment: OMG thanks for your answer thai is very useful fo me, but i still have some question, (1)the "left-hand side is vector cross product" that is mean R matrix by v vector is cross product, i not really know that meaning which have relative proof ? and (2)the "Two matrices A,B of the same shape are equal iff for every vector $v$, $Av$ =$Bv$ . "this mean i know, but this property does have a noun to called?

Comment: And i have external question, the column vector of u product row vector of u in the  formula this product is called out product are not dot or cross product right ? and out product of two vector result is a matrix that is right ?

Comment: You're welcome, @Haseo (1) I am not talking about R in that sentence. I'm taking about the third equation I wrote down, which is only about the cross product: $$\hat u \times \vec v = [\hat u]_\times \vec v
$$ (2) I don't know what it's called, but you can prove it very easily using a basis (3) maybe? I don't know the name, sorry

Comment: I have is a last question in this formula that  $u^u^T$ is the out product 
or tensor product and result is a matrix, which is different to cross product that result is a vector right ?

Comment: @Haseo yes, this is correct (if $\hat u$  is a column vector, then $\hat u^T$ is a row vector, and $3\times1$ matrix times $1\times 3$ matrix is a $3\times 3$ matrix)